# Notepad++ first and last letter uppercase

Tags: notepad++

How can I convert

like this screenshot
https://img.techpowerup.org/200421/test.jpg

```
Alfred
World
Hello
Example
Google
Testing
```

to

```
AlfreD
WorlD
HellO
Example
GooglE
TestinG
```

I have hundreds of lines and want to convert all like this, thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SU is not a regex writing service, you need to show you've invested some effort in finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\w)(\w*)(\w)`
- Replace with: `\u$1\E$2\u$3`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\w)        # group 1, 1rst word character
(\w*)       # group 2, 0 or more word characters
(\w)        # group 3, last word character
```

**Replacement:**

```
\u          # uppercased the following
$1          # content of group 1, the 1rst letter
\E          # remove uppercase
$2          # content of group 2
\u          # uppercased the following
$3          # content of group 3, the last letter
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]